How to sum multiple columns with multiple conditions
I have a table as below:



COA
100
101
102
200
201
202
300




11000000000
1000
1200
1100
1000
1200
1100
1800


11200100000
1500
1400
1300
1500
1400
1300
1700



I want to sum 100, 101, 102 to one group and 200, 201, 202 to one group and 300 to one group. Below is my expected Output:
First Table:



COA
100+
200+
300




11000000000
3300
3300
1800


11200100000
4200
4200
1700



Second Table: Assuming that the 2 COAs belong to 1 big COA and I want to add the totals of both those big COAs by group.



COA
100+
200+
300




11000000000 & 11200100000
7500
7500
3500



How can I get expected Output. Thank you.

is the group of 100, 101 and 102 (and for 200+ and 300+ respectivly) always the same? or is it variable in size?

Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

@Excellor: It maybe changes. I’m assumming that 101, 102, 103 belongs to 100+. So what I want is sum up data with 2 conditions: Columns header is 100, 101, 102 and COA is 11000000000

@RonRosenfeld: Sorry I’m not on PC now, I will try to edit as soon as possible. Actually I tried with sumifs but it not worked. I can handle it with python but don’t know how to do with excel.

For the first table: =SUM(IF((LEFT($B$1:$H$1,1)=LEFT(B$15,1))*($A16=$A$2:$A$3),$B$2:$H$3,""))
This formula can be dragged right and down as needed.
Refer to the image below to see what each arguments contains/refers to.


For Table 2: =SUM(IF((LEFT($B$1:$H$1,1)=LEFT(B19,1))*((CHOOSEROWS(TEXTSPLIT($A20,," & "),1)*1=$A$2:$A$3)+(CHOOSEROWS(TEXTSPLIT($A20,," & "),2)*1=$A$2:$A$3)),$B$2:$H$3,""))
Here you have to make sure that your COA is always formatted the same: ### & ###.


I suspect there might be an easier/better way to do Table 2, but it works.

Thank you so much , it worked. Just a note that I need to hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make it work..

By the way, I have another question that if I want to specify columns header in code instead of using Left. I will do as below:
=SUM(IF(($B$1:$H$1=100)*($A16=$A$2:$A$3),$B$2:$H$3,""))+SUM(IF(($B$1:$H$1=101)*($A16=$A$2:$A$3),$B$2:$H$3,"")) Is there any way better? Thank you.

Strange that you had to use CSE, what version of Excel are you using? - Your formula seems to work, you could shorten it a little: =SUM(IF(($B$1:$H$1=100)*($A16=$A$2:$A$3),$B$2:$H$3,""),(IF(($B$1:$H$1=101)*($A16=$A$2:$A$3),$B$2:$H$3,""))) (making each IF() part of the SUM(). If that makes sense.

I'm using 2016 version of Excel. Maybe it's old version so I need to hi CSE.

Using SUMPRODUCT and MAKEARRAY:
First
=LET(
    tbCOA, A1:H3,
    coa, DROP(INDEX(tbCOA, , 1), 1),
    amts, DROP(tbCOA, 1, 1),
    amt_header, DROP(INDEX(tbCOA, 1, ), , 1),
    amt_group, --SUBSTITUTE(B7:D7, "+", ""),
    sum_amt, LAMBDA(coa_row, amt_grp_col,
        SUMPRODUCT(
            amts * (INDEX(coa, coa_row, 1) = coa) *
                IFERROR(
                    N(XMATCH(amt_header, amt_group, -1) = amt_grp_col),
                    0
                )
        )
    ),
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(coa), COLUMNS(amt_group), sum_amt)
)


Second
=LET(
    tbCOA, A1:H3,
    coa, DROP(INDEX(tbCOA, , 1), 1),
    coas, A14,
    amts, DROP(tbCOA, 1, 1),
    amt_header, DROP(INDEX(tbCOA, 1, ), , 1),
    amt_group, --SUBSTITUTE(B7:D7, "+", ""),
    sum_amt, LAMBDA(coa_row, amt_grp_col,
        SUMPRODUCT(
            amts *
                ISNUMBER(XMATCH(coa, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(coas, coa_row, 1), "&")))) *
                IFERROR(N(XMATCH(amt_header, amt_group, -1) = amt_grp_col), 0)
        )
    ),
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(coas), COLUMNS(amt_group), sum_amt)
)



Thank you, it's quite complicated. I will try it.
